# Xamarin IOS UIColor.FromName always returns white color?

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

I am attempting to alter the background color of a UIView, using a named color defined in the Assets.xcssets.

```
myViewBack.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromName("MyColor1");
```

But no matter what I try, the above line always seems to return a color that suspiciously looks like UIColor.White.

Am I missing something obvious here?

(Visual Studio for Mac v7.5)

Comment: 1) Does the color set name actually match the name you are trying to load? (MyColors.xcassets/**{YourColorName}**.colorset)` 2) I would look at the json file itself to confirm that the color(s) within the `xcassets` file is actually correct (i.e. `MyColors.xcassets/MyRed.colorset`) and that the correct idioms are assigned with the proper color, i.e. are you just setting the `universal` color and not the others? etc...

Comment: Personally due to the problems that VS has properly assigning the the json correctly and due to the fact that you can not remove the idioms you are not using, i.e. I want to assign `universal` and delete all the others, which you can do in Xcode (or manually in the json) but not in VS, I just use Xcode to create/edit the assets and then add the file(s) into the iOS project (assets are a `ItemGroup` with `ImageAsset` subtypes).

Comment: Hmm, I did only set the Universal color (as I would do in Xcode), but when I assign the iPhone color instead it does work. That solves my problem, but it is not the behaviour I would expect.

Comment: Yes, that is one of the problems, xamarin creates the full json color set with all the idioms set to White and you can not disable them in VS, Xcode generates the json the "correct way" and allows you to disable idioms